# Chaining observables with RxJS in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have 2 API calls -- the second call uses something the first call returns. With promises this was easy:

```
myService.findAll()

     // First call
    .then(response => {
        return myService.findSpecific(response.something);
    })

    .then(response => {
        // result from second API call
    });
```

How would I do this using observables?

Comment: A good thing to remember is that in RXJS Promises can be treated as Observables that will at most emit a single item (the resolved data).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can leverage the `flatMap` operator this way:

```
myService.findAll()
  // First call
  .flatMap(response => {
    return myService.findSpecific(response.something);
  }).subscribe(response => {
    // result from second API call
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me! +1